# Hide image if item in ng-repeat is last

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code:

```
<li class="child-item" role="menuitem" ng-show="isSubMenu" ng-repeat="sublink in subLinks" ng-class="{'last' : $last && setLastElemFlag($last) || false}" ng-click="stopPropagation()">
    <img id="child-item-bullet" /><span class="sub-child-span">{{sublink.name}}</span>
    <img id="child-dotted-lines-bottom" ng-hide="isLastElement"/>
    <img id="child-dotted-lines-bottom-2" ng-hide="isLastElement" />
</li>
```

Below is my setLastElemFlag function:

```
$scope.setLastElemFlag = function (value) {
    alert(value);
    $scope.isLastElement = value;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is I want to hide child-dotted-lines-bottom and child-dotted-lines-bottom-2 once the item in ng-repeat is the last one. But instead of hiding only the last pair, the above code hides all instances of the image.

To make things much clearer, this is what I want to achieve:

[image: Expected output]

but instead I got this:

[image: wrong output]

What's wrong with my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it like that, using `$last`:

```
<li class="child-item" role="menuitem" ng-show="isSubMenu" ng-repeat="sublink in subLinks" ng-class="{'last' : $last && setLastElemFlag($last) || false}" ng-click="stopPropagation()">
    <img id="child-item-bullet" /><span class="sub-child-span">{{sublink.name}}</span>
    <img id="child-dotted-lines-bottom" ng-hide="$last"/>
    <img id="child-dotted-lines-bottom-2" ng-hide="$last" />
</li>
```

Here are [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Comment: Thank you! It's working as intended. I just removed references to the function since it doesn't serve any purpose anymore. Will mark this as answer in a while. :D